# Online beamer presentation viewer

Tags: beamer, presentations, online

I recently attended a talk at my university that ran into some embarrassing technical difficulties. The speaker created his talk in beamer and had the presentation as a .pdf on his flash-drive but the computer that was setup for the projector only had Google Chrome available to view .pdf files. Google Chrome has a "presentation" mode but doesn't allow natural slide transitions (I understand that you can go to the next slide through the spacebar but the speaker was unable to reference previous slides easily and naturally).

I was wondering if there is a website where the presentation could have been uploaded and allows presentations to have a similar experience that they would on most standard .pdf viewers.